# Why is this not JSON?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

```
"{"ops": [{"insert": "Ajax story content."}]}"
```

I am trying to send json from a django view to my template and play with it with JS.  Why can I not parse this?

When I run JSON.parse() I am given an error that says
VM817:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
in JSON at position 40
at JSON.parse ()
at :1:6

I've run it through JSONLint and it gives me an error

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
"{"ops ": [{"insert ":
---^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'
```

To me, it looks like valid JSON.  What's up?

Comment: What, *exactly*, are you passing to `json.parse` as an argument? Are the outer quotes actually part of the value?

Comment: What happens if the first and last quotes are removed.  As currently `”{“` is the first value, rather than `”ops”`.

Answer (score 1):

Because  your double Quotes, change them to simple quotes !

```
'{"ops": [{"insert": "Ajax story content."}]}'
```